# Segmentation fault when calling a Ruby function using C api

Tags: c, ruby, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to call simple ruby function using Ruby C API, When executing the compiled output I get segmentation fault, I'm not sure what is the problem, I hope you can help me, Thanks.

**C Code (./func.c)**

```
#include <ruby.h>
int main(){
 VALUE obj;
 VALUE result;
 VALUE map;
 ruby_init();
 rb_require("./func.rb");
 obj=rb_str_new_cstr("");
 map = rb_hash_new();
 rb_hash_aset(map, rb_str_new2("key"),rb_str_new2("val"));

 result = rb_funcall(obj, rb_intern("func"), 1, map);
 return 0;
}
```

**Ruby Code (./func.rb)**

```
def func(opts)
    puts opts['key']
end
```

**Compile flags**

```
gcc func.c -o func -I/home/wh/.rbenv/versions/2.1.6/include/ruby-2.1.0/x86_64-linux -I/home/wh/.rbenv/versions/2.1.6/include/ruby-2.1.0 -L/home/wh/.rbenv/versions/2.1.6/lib/ -lruby-static -lm -pthread -lcrypt -ldl -rdynamic
```

**Segmentation fault when running ./func**

```
<main>: [BUG] Segmentation fault at 0x00000000000018
ruby 2.1.6p336 (2015-04-13 revision 50298) [x86_64-linux]

-- Control frame information -----------------------------------------------
c:0001 p:0000 s:0002 E:002468 TOP    [FINISH]


-- C level backtrace information -------------------------------------------
./func() [0x581bcc] vm_dump.c:690
./func() [0x5f4893] error.c:312
./func(rb_bug+0xb3) [0x5f5a73] error.c:339
./func() [0x4f6c83] signal.c:824
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x10340) [0x7f805628d340] ../nptl/sysdeps/pthread/funlockfile.c:29
./func() [0x416f03] eval_intern.h:157
./func(rb_require_safe+0x63c) [0x42038c] load.c:1017
./func(main+0x18) [0x418b05]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf5) [0x7f8055ed9ec5] libc-start.c:287
./func() [0x418a23] enumerator.c:181

-- Other runtime information -----------------------------------------------

Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: For what it’s worth, your code works ok for me, although with a different OS, compiler and Ruby version (Mac, clang and Ruby versions 2.3.0 and 2.2.3).

Comment: I just tried ruby 2.2.3 + clang 3.4 and I'm still getting a segmentation fault.

Comment: It looks like it can't find `./func.rb` (probably LoadError but it could be something else). Try wrapping everything after the `ruby_init()` call into a function and then pass it to `rb_protect()` otherwise raising exceptions may cause segfaults. Embedding MRI has many pitfalls.

Comment: I added the wrapper to `rb_require` and `rb_funcall`, there is no segmenration fault but it fails and the value of state is `6`        `rb_protect(RUBY_METHOD_FUNC(rb_require), (VALUE) '"./func.rb",&state);`
        `if(state){`
                `printf("rb_require Error %d\n",state);
        }`

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a lack of canonical examples of how to embed ruby (at least in the official documentation). The best thing I can find is this [free chapter](https://media.pragprog.com/titles/ruby3/ext_ruby.pdf) from the pickaxe which says that you need

```
ruby_sysinit(&argc, &argv);
RUBY_INIT_STACK;
ruby_init();
ruby_init_loadpath();
```

To setup the ruby interpreter. You're missing some of that, in particular given that your crash happens inside `require`, the missing `ruby_init_loadpath` seems suspicious.

In [this thread](https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/137935) (in which Dave Thomas is asking about changes to embedding ruby) Nobu also says that you need

```
RUBY_GLOBAL_SETUP
```

before main.

You may also be interested in mruby, which has been designed to be easy to embed.

Comment: I tried your suggestion, I'm getting the same segmentation fault.

Comment: Exactly the same backtrack?

Comment: I think so, https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6d147bc68490f24cc480b8bf37805756, btw I get this warning: data definition has no type or storage class [enabled by default] on RUBY_GLOBAL_SETUP;